# Having empty values in Jade for proper layout?

Tags: layout, pug

As shown I have an address field that would look best if on two lines.  Here it is shown with a period (.) to make it work.  Can I have Jade with a "p" tag that has no value inside to make the double lined address field show up properly?
[Layout with period](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8112c.png)

Here is the code for it with the "p" tag in question is in the middle:

```
.panel.panel-primary
    .panel-heading
      h2.panel-title
        | #{appointment.location} Information
    .panel-body
      p 
        | Distance:
        span.pull-right.badge-default= appointment.distance
      p 
        | Address:
        span.pull-right.badge-default= appointment.address.street
      p.span.pull-right.badge-default= appointment.address.region
      p .     
      p 
        | Phone Number:
        span.pull-right.badge-default= appointment.phoneNumber
      each time in appointment.openingTimes
        p
          | #{time.days}: 
          if time.closed
            span.pull-right.badge-default closed
          else
            span.pull-right.badge-default #{time.opening} - #{time.closing}
```

Without the period this is what it looks like:
[Layout with p tag empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qISvU.png)

And the code behind it:

```
.panel.panel-primary
    .panel-heading
      h2.panel-title
        | #{appointment.location} Information
    .panel-body
      p 
        | Distance:
        span.pull-right.badge-default= appointment.distance
      p 
        | Address:
        span.pull-right.badge-default= appointment.address.street
      p.span.pull-right.badge-default= appointment.address.region
      p      
      p 
        | Phone Number:
        span.pull-right.badge-default= appointment.phoneNumber
      each time in appointment.openingTimes
        p
          | #{time.days}: 
          if time.closed
            span.pull-right.badge-default closed
          else
            span.pull-right.badge-default #{time.opening} - #{time.closing}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not put a break-tag instead of the p-tag with the dot? Or give the p-tag with the second address-span some margin-bottom.

```
  p 
    | Address:
    span.pull-right.badge-default= appointment.address.street
    br
    span.pull-right.badge-default= appointment.address.region
    br     
  p 
    | Phone Number:
```

Comment: I am new to Jade and HTML in general so I never thought of it!  This is what  the br tag looked like: http://i.imgur.com/1kalO0r.png   For your next suggestion of some margin bottom, that would be through CSS?

Comment: Yes with css. Try my edit above first, and if that doesn't work do it with css.

Comment: Almost there!  http://i.imgur.com/XoTfI6w.png  For the minor spacing issues, just do that with CSS?